# Github Workflow npm build fails on relative path

Tags: reactjs, github, workflow

I'm using the following for building my react web app on Github:

```
jobs:
  buildWeb:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: Web
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install and build Web
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build-prod
```

The workflow correctly sets the working-directory to 'web' and installs the dependencies.
However, when it starts to build the app, it fails with:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/elements/Login/LoginComponent.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../Services/AuthenticationService' in '/home/runner/work/project/project/Web/src/components/elements/Login'
```

Locally the app gets build correctly. This error occurs on every imported component within my app, excluding modules in de node_modules app (since npm i didn't give any errors).

Why doesn't this work? Am I missing something?

Comment: So.. 2 years later I had the same issue and actually Google'd to find my own question posted here 2 years ago. Problem had to do with obfuscation of some classNames or images :)